# Unable to use datetime.proto definition after installing proto-google-common-protos

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, quarkus, grpc-java, quarkus-grpc

I have a gRPC-based project in Quarkus. I have to return some data fetched from a PostgreSQL database, where some of the columns are of `timestamp without time zone` type — mapped to `LocalDateTime` in Java.

```sql
create table users (
  id          uuid                        not null default gen_random_uuid(),
  ...
  created_on  timestamp without time zone not null default localtimestamp(6),
  modified_on timestamp without time zone not null default localtimestamp(6),
  primary key (id)
);
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/type/datetime.proto"; <- Doesn't work :/

...

message GetUserResponse {
  optional string id = 1;
  ...
  optional google.type.DateTime created_on = 5;
  optional google.type.DateTime modified_on = 6;
}
```

```java
public class User {
  private UUID id;

  ...

  private LocalDateTime createdOn;

  private LocalDateTime modifiedOn;
}
```

I've tried importing `com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.33.0` into the project so I can use `google/type/datetime.proto`, but somehow the types are not getting recognized.

```bash
$ ./gradlew clean quarkusBuild 
> Task :clean
> Task :processResources
google/type/datetime.proto: File not found.
user.proto:12:1: Import "google/type/datetime.proto" was not found or had errors.
user.proto:43:12: "google.type.DateTime" is not defined.
user.proto:44:12: "google.type.DateTime" is not defined.
```

> **NOTE:** I can certainly use `OffsetDateTime` in Java because I see that `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto` is recognized. Both `OffsetDateTime` and `LocalDateTime` will let me store what I want, because I use UTC across the board, but I would rather solve the problem and avoid changing too many things which might break some others.

Is there a way to *register* the types coming from `com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos`? My assumption is that just by importing that library they should be available.

---

#### Update

There is a Quarkus [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-generation-reference#configuring-grpc-code-generation-for-dependencies) for gRPC code generation. I think this may solve this problem, but so far, using `quarkus.generate-code.grpc.scan-for-imports`, `quarkus.generate-code.grpc.scan-for-proto`, or `quarkus.generate-code.grpc.scan-for-proto-include.` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm familiar with protos and less with Java and not with Quarkus. With Protocol Buffers there are **two** sources. The first is the protocol buffer source that `protoc` compiles into, in this case, Java. In this case, the second, is the Java sources. Gradle needs to access the [`google.type.DateTime`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/datetime.proto) protocol buffer source so that it can use `protoc` to generate the Java sources that include the references.

Comment: One way (possibly not the best but.... unfamiliar with Quarkus) would be to clone the [`googleapis`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) repo that includes Google's gRPC and Protocol Buffer sources (including `DateTime`) **and** you will need to ensure that Gradle can include the cloned folder as a `proto_path`.

Comment: I guess you might be right. I'm not terribly familiar with `gRPC` in general, but looks like the `.proto` files must be in the `proto_path`. I guess Gradle doesn't know where to look for those. Will open up a GitHub issue to see what's their answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gRPC Code Generation Reference Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-generation-reference) documents different ways to scan/include/generate code based on what's available in the project.

In my case, since I already had `com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos` in the dependencies, I just wanted to make all the `*.proto` files available in the project, so I used `scan-for-imports`:

```yaml
quarkus:
  generate-code:
    grpc:
      scan-for-imports: all
```

There is also a way to **scan only** the specified dependencies by group and artifact. This is much better, but the syntax is a little bit awkward.